# Wordpress - Which hook should I use to capture $_POST('password') via profile update and password reset

Tags: wordpress, post, woocommerce, hook, password-hash

I need to rehash the password which the user entered during Wordpress registration (I use WooCommerce)

Im successfully able to do this with

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['password'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
    }

}
```

however I need to do this for 2 more occasions , **profile update** and **reset password**

I wrote

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['password'] ) || '' == $_POST['password'] ) {
        return;
    }
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
    $x = $_POST['password'];
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert('.$x.')';
    echo '</script>';


    // password changed...
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```

it doesnt work at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
       update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', (string) $_POST['password_1']);
    }
    // password changed...
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: I added this for people like me struggling for hours searching this, okay I will try to edit it in a proper way